# Customized Listview with Numberpicker in android 4.0

Tags: android, numberpicker

I need to develop a task with the concept of Providing points to the Competitors. It must be done Dynamically. So i have chosen the NumberPicker for the Points value. I need to list the Competitors from the Database and it will be in two separate columns such as Id and Name.

While the run time i need to Evaluate and Put Points to them by using NumberPicker with a range of 0-10.

And i need to Get the value from the NumberPicker to the Textview and store the Value in my Database

Please Help me for my Task..

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I have a ListView with 3 columns.

Comment: With 2 Textvciews and One Numberpicker,.. I couldn't access the numberPicker in ListView